# Visualforce pages in a link at Object header

Tags: visualforce

[image]Can any one let me know how to link a Visualforce page which is in a pdf format at the Object header.
I mean when the user clicks the link, it should open in pdf format. Any suggestions please.

Comment: I think your question may be confusing. Can you post a screenshot of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @sfdcfox:PFA SCREENSHOT.This is my VF page,i would like it to link at Object header,when clicked the VF page should get opened with the data in PDF format.Any Suggestion plz

Comment: You have missed the image. :)

Comment: @MahmoodButt:PFA Screenshot

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is use the

```
renderAs="pdf"
```

attribute on your apex:page tag.  There's more about how this works [here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_quick_start_renderas_pdf.htm).  You can use CSS to affect the appearance of the PDF page.  There are, of course, [limitations](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_output_pdf_considerations.htm).

Comment: I don't think this is what they're after, though. It sounds to me as if they want a link on a detail page that opens a Visualforce page when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can render any page as a PDF by adding the renderAs attribute to the  component, and specifying “pdf” as the rendering service. For example:

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf">
```

Visualforce pages rendered as PDFs will either display in the browser or download as a PDF file, depending on your browser settings.

For Example :-

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" renderAs="pdf" applyBodyTag="false">
    <head>
        <style> 
            body { font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS'; }
            .companyName { font: bold 30px; color: red; }  
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
        <h1>New Account Name!</h1>

        <apex:panelGrid columns="1" width="100%">
            <apex:outputText value="{!account.Name}" styleClass="companyName"/>
            <apex:outputText value="{!NOW()}"></apex:outputText>
        </apex:panelGrid>
        </center>
    </body>
</apex:page>
```

Things to note about the page:

`<script>` is CSS markup, not Visualforce markup. It defines the font family used for the entire page, as well as a particular style for the company name.

Some of the output text is contained in an  component. A panel grid renders as an HTML table. Each component found in the body of the  component is placed into a corresponding cell in the first row until the number of columns is reached. As there is only a single cell, each output text is displayed in a separate row.

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/images/dev_guides/pages/images/pages_quick_start_render_as_pdf.png

There are some limitations for Rendering Visaulforce page as PDF . Please refer to below link to get full limitations over the visualforce page.

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_output_pdf_considerations.htm